# Can't install nvidia-driver in ubuntu 20.04.2 kernel version 5.8.0-55

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia

## Problem

I can't install nvidia-driver-460 in newly installed ubuntu 20.04.
I ran command
`sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`
then I got errors bellow.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-modules-nvidia-460-generic-hwe-20.04 : Depends: linux-modules-nvidia-460-5.8.0-55-generic (= 5.8.0-55.62~20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                                              Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-460 (<= 460.80-1) but 460.84-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

## Status

### Ubuntu version is

```
cat /etc/os-release
```

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

### kernel version

```
uname -a
```

```
Linux ~~ 5.8.0-55-generic #62~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 2 08:55:04 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

### drivers list

```
ubuntu-drivers list
```

```
nvidia-driver-460, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-460-generic-hwe-20.04)
nvidia-driver-418-server, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-418-server-generic-hwe-20.04)
nvidia-driver-460-server, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-460-server-generic-hwe-20.04)
nvidia-driver-465, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-465-generic-hwe-20.04)
nvidia-driver-450-server, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-450-server-generic-hwe-20.04)
```

### devices list

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001E07sv000010DEsd000012A4bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : TU102 [GeForce RTX 2080 Ti Rev. A]
driver   : nvidia-driver-460-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-460 - third-party non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-418-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-465 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-450-server - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

## What I tried

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Why I can't install `nvidia-drivers` via `ubuntu-driver autoinstall`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories) as I can't reproduce on fresh VM.